# How to calculate rotation angle using Android Sensors?

Tags: android, orientation

I am doing an Opengl appln in which i have to rotate the camera, if the android device is rotated/tilted along Z axis.

I tried the `SensorManager.getOrientation(R, orientVals);` using the magnetic and accelerometer sensors. But the values are very much fluctuating.
Gyroscope is also available in my device.

Since I am animating (rotate) the camera, I need a smooth rotation values

Please guide me in this regard.

Comment: As you have the gyroscope, use that. the magnetic/acceleration sensor causes lots of noise (which you can compensate for, but gyrscope is loads better).
Here's a video that explains a bit more: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s19W-MG-whE

Comment: Gyroscopes produce excellent, reliable values but aren't terribly ubiquitous. If you want your app to run on lots of devices, you'll want to stick with the way you're doing it now. I found that a simple moving average was the best way to fix the values. It incurs a slight delay but is far smoother.

Answer (score 1):

See [How do you calculate the rate of rotation using the accelerometer values in Android for a particular axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22512348/how-do-you-calculate-the-rate-of-rotation-using-the-accelerometer-values-in-andr/22516740#22516740) on how to read Android's software-derived sensors that combine the data from the accelerometers, magnetometers, and (if available) gyroscopes.

To smooth values, use a low-pass filter or (better but more complicated) a [Kalman filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter). I suspect that Android's software-derived sensors such as the "rotation sensor" already use a Kalman filter to combine data from the different sensors. (One could search the source code...)