# Auto rotation should work in specific angle in Android

Tags: android

Auto rotation is too fast to close my activity.

When I rotate App then on create then it call web service which loads data from server using Async Task. But when I rotate too fast then it closes my activity.

I think if rotation angle is increased then problem become solved... I want to rotate only some specific angle in landscape and portrait. Because small angle on rotation can cause on create call again and again.

Comment: Please express yourself in a better english

Comment: The problem is not with rotation, but in the amount of time you are taking in async task and what you are doing there. Please post the code, people here will be able to help you out

Comment: new AyncdataFromServer().execute(new String[] { Serverurl, Emp });

  new AyncConfigData().execute(new String[] { Serverurl, Emp });

  Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRefesh);
  btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ;
    new AyncdataFromServer()
      .execute(new String[] { Serverurl, Emp });

    new AyncConfigData().execute(new String[] { Serverurl, Emp });

   }
  });

Answer (score 0):

That really isn't the way to do it. You have to use some more precise sensor, like the gyroscope. First, you have to programatically check if the running device has it, because not all devices support it. Alternatively, use the magnetic or acceleration sensor. Already discussed here:

[How to calculate rotation angle using Android Sensors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8488911/how-to-calculate-rotation-angle-using-android-sensors)